# in rails difference between form_for @article and form_for :article

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im new to ruby on rails, abit confused between the usage of the following when i try to update a record:

1. `<%= form_for @article, url:{action: "update"} do |form| %>`
   this one works, but i dont understand how come the submit button says 'update article'
2. `<%= form_for :article, url:{action: "update"} do |form| %>`
   this one throws No route matches [POST] "/articles/2", and the submit button says 'save article'

finally:

3. `<%= form_with(model: @article) do |form| %>`
   actually updates the record, but i dont understand why it's calling update, and not other methods

Comment: Do you store record in @article instance variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `form_for(@article)` creates a form builder which is bound to a model instance.

If `@article` is nil it will raise an error.

If the instance is a new record the form will use `method="POST"` and `action="/arcticles"`.

If the record has been persisted it will have `method="PATCH"` and `action="/arcticles/:article_id"`.

Rails derives the URL for the action attribute based on convention over configuration. So there is no need to explicitly pass the url option if you follow the conventions.

An example of this would be:

```
<% @article = Article.new(title: 'Hello World') %>
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_input :title %>
<% end %>
```

This will render something like:

```
<form action="/articles" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="article[title]" value="Hello World"/>
  ...
</form>
```

> `<%= form_for @article, url:{action: "update"} do |form| %>` this one
>   works, but i dont understand how come the submit button says 'update
>   article'

The form builder knows it is updating an record by calling `.new_record?` on the the record you passed to `form_with`. You can change the default value of the submit button by providing translations:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      create: "Save new record"
      update: "Save changes"
```

#### `form_for(:article)` creates a scoped form builder that does not wrap an object.

This creates a form builder where the inputs will be "scoped". For example:

```
<%= form_for(:article) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_input :title %>
<% end %>
```

This will render something like:

```
<form action="/articles" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="article[title]"/>
  ...
</form>
```

Rails derives the URL for the action attribute based on convention over configuration.

In your case `<%= form_for :article, url:{action: "update"} do |form| %>` causes a routing error since `form_for` defaults to `method: "POST"`.

#### `form_with` is the Rails 5.1 replacement for `form_for` and `form_tag`

`form_with` will replace the `form_for` and `form_tag` methods which are closely related yet have very different signatures. `form_for` and `form_tag` have been soft depreciated and are slated for removal.

The idea is to provide a single method with a more consistent signature.

If you are using Rails 5.1+ this is what you should be using.

#### See:

- [Rails Guides - Action View Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)
- [Rails API - ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)
- [Rails 5.1's form_with vs. form_tag vs. form_for](https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on `@artical`. If `@artical` is new object (`id` in `@artical` is `nil`) is call the create action. If `@artical` is existing object then it called the update method.