# Rails Form: field_for polymorphic association with belongs_to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form on a model called "Patient", which has_one "Role" via polymorphic association. And the "Role" has_one "User". And I need to modify the "User" field "first_name" via a form...

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :role, :as => :roleable, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :role
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

    belongs_to :roleable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
end

class PatientsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
        # This works just fine, so I know the data is there
        puts(@patient.role.user.first_name)
    end
end
```

How do I make a form that includes this field? This is what I have so far that isn't working:

```
<%= form_for(:patient, url: edit_patient_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :role do |r| %>
        <%= r.fields_for :user do |u| %>
            <%= u.text_field :first_name, value: u.first_name, class: "value", disabled: false %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But unfortunately this is not working:

```
undefined method `first_name' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007f82d30c4ad8>
```

Comment: What you mean by not working? Are there any error messages? Are there logs showing something?

Comment: Sorry, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your form to `<%= form_for(@patient) %>` so that it wraps the @patient object.

Use `.object` to get the object wrapped by the form builder.

```
<%= u.text_field :first_name, value: u.object.first_name, class: "value", disabled: false %>
```

But you don't need to explicitly assign the value in the first place and the disabled attribute defaults to false:

```
<%= u.text_field :first_name, class: "value" %>
```

Comment: Ah, you should be using `<%= form_for(@patient) %>` not `:patient`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745589/in-rails-difference-between-form-for-article-and-form-for-article/49750116#49750116

Comment: Yes... that fixes it. I'll need to look up why this is, and what the difference is between using @patient or :patient when you create a form, because everything I've seen shows to always use :patient

Comment: I think I get it now. :patient is for creating a new Patient, where as @patient is necessary when updating an existing one.

Comment: Kind of - its better to just use `<%= form_for(@patient) %>` for both cases and set `@patient = Patient.new` in the controller as it lets you use the exact same view partial. Even `<%= form_for(@patient || Patient.new) %>` is better.

Comment: For Rails 5.1+ you want to use `form_with(model: @patient)`

Comment: There are very few cases where you actually want to use `form_for` with a symbol. I'm not sure if the I18n lookup works properly for example without a model.